# Html Design difference between IE11 & Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I got an existing webpage, where I had inserted a select list for language selection, my issue that on the Internet Explorer the design is faulty, I mean there is a lot of spacing in the menu but only on this part. I want to eliminate that excessive spacing before the list and after the submit button.
[image]

The code for the list is the following

```
        <tr>
            <TD  class=blue12bold vAlign=top background="Control_files/bg_navi.gif"  height="5%"><BR />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Language
            </TD> 
        </TR>
                <tr>
                    <td class ="second" align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <form method="POST" >
                            <SELECT name="language"  >
                                <?php
                                    $lang_select_list_array = array("ro","en","de");
                                    foreach ($lang_select_list_array as $value) {
                                        echo "<option value=\"$value\"";
                                        if ($value == $language) {
                                            echo " selected ";}
                                        echo ">$value</option>";
                                        }

                                ?>
                            </SELECT>
                            <br />
                            <input type="submit" value="Set" style="height:20px; width:80px">

                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: I think you have a problem with reset css. as I see a slight change in line-height, and table default properties. if you see the title "Language" some spacing at top and bottom is visible in IE explorer. check if you are having any height in ".second" class properties.

Comment: I had rewrote this menu.php what is a child frame, it was html 4.0 before and now using html 5 it is the same view on all of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing from html 4.0 to html 5 and now it is shows in the same way on all the browsers.